# What's the meaning of gradle task compileRdm in android build gradle tasks?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

What is the rdm meaning, why it's name is compileRdmDebugSources but not just compileDebugSources?
[image]

I search every, but I cant't found some docs about Kotlin rdm. And my CI report some error in this task:

```
* What went wrong:Execution failed for task ':MainProj:compileRdmDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork  
> Cannot run program "/tools/jdk/1.8.0_161/jre/bin/java": error=7, Argument list too long
```

Comment: Can you give the latest release nightly a try (https://gradle.org/release-nightly/), And try to update the gradle wrapper

Comment: Might some code  wrong but the compiler could not found the issue. Enable compiler stack trace and try to find the log what went wrong.

Comment: @MohammedAlloboany Actually, I does't want update gradle for now, nightly looks like need gradle 6+?

Comment: Trying , but it's not appear every time, a dozen times a weak. And I want to know what rdm is more.

Comment: @RainFool Yes , need 6.4 . I think updating gradle will solve it , have you tried to stack trace if you find the error?

Comment: @MohammedAlloboany I added --statcktrace, but this error is not appeal every build time, so I'm waiting now.